# ng-cli doesn't add components to the app module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I’ve encountered a problem with a component generation using anglular-cli
ng-cli doesn’t add the brand-new created component to the app module:

```
$ ng g component Try
installing component
  create src\app\try\try.component.css
  create src\app\try\try.component.html
  create src\app\try\try.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\try\try.component.ts
  update src\app\app.module.ts
No app module found. Please add your new class to your component.
```

I didn’t move any file. The project structure is default. The `src\app\app.module.ts` exists and has the following content:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTES} from "./app.routes";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],

    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Everything looks like ok.

Comment: @Kinduser this is simply command line prompt

Comment: @Kinduser but where? I wish I knew on what things generator is based when he looks for app module...

Comment: C:\webProj\EngMe\web_engme

Comment: of course, I run `ng` from this folder. it won't work otherwise at all.

Comment: @Kinduser sure, here it is: https://github.com/zhekaus/ng-generate-problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, finally, let’s close my issue. I'm very sorry, I’ll be verbose, since this problem have been making my nerves.

As to me, it was some king of bug in the latest version of ng-cli or probably in its incompatibility with latest version of related components.
The source of problem was in my updating of all the modules mentioned in `package.json` up to the latest stable version.

Problem was confidently reproducible. However by now it looks like Angular Team has solved something and, after the last updating, everything has become fine.
What I did to solve it:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm uninstall angular-cli @angular/cli -–save-dev
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest


# let’s update all the local again packages to the latest ones with this funny utility:
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u -a --packageFile package.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Now I have the following versions and everything is working:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.42",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "pug-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.6",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

Let's try again:

```
$ ng generate component NewOne
installing component
  create src\app\new-one\new-one.component.css
  create src\app\new-one\new-one.component.html
  create src\app\new-one\new-one.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\new-one\new-one.component.ts
  update src\app\app.module.ts
```

Fine.

Comment: I did all the steps you mentioned. But After all the steps it says "The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found." Can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ng generate component menu(Component name) --module=app(root app module).module
```